# What can cause to get into a hopeless git state, where "git rebase --continue" does not work?

Tags: git

I had a problem yesterday I am not able to reproduce. But I am pretty sure many people have seen the same error.

I was in the middle of fixing a tiny simple git conflict, I did `git add` the changes and then did a `git rebase --continue` where I got the following output:

```
Applying: Better Copyright check (with year); exception for BluePyOpt License
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

However, `git status` shows there is nothing to add:

```
$ git st
rebase in progress; onto 4e1e5a8
You are currently rebasing branch 'dev' on '4e1e5a8'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

What can cause such a state you never can exit? (I want to reproduce this problem to find a solution myself even I can understand).

Comment: Look like you initiated a rebase with no changes. Are you sure you did not forget to commit after adding the file?

Comment: The first error message does not say anything about doing a commit. Just an 'add'.

Comment: It doesnt say it directly but it does say there is no change so the rebase it pointless. No change could mean there is no file commited, or it could mean something else. I never use rebase, its just an idea.

Comment: You almost certainly want to run `git rebase --skip`, as in the 2nd-to-last line of advice. What gets you here: you have a commit that makes some change, but someone else already made a bigger change that *includes* the change you made in your commit. Resolving the conflict leaves the bigger change in place, so that your commit does nothing at all.

Comment: Might it be possible that this specific commit is now "empty", i.e. by resolving the conflicts no changes are there? Then you just skip this commit in the rebase process.

Comment: There is nobody else involved. Just me and the remote repository!

Comment: @Alex I have encountered this message many times, and every time it was because the commit ended up empty given changes already present in the branch I was rebasing onto, as others have suggested here. Faced with this message, I pretty much always do `git rebase --skip` followed by `git rebase --continue`. Sometimes it's because I've already cherry-picked that bug fix across the two branches, sometimes I've independently done the fix on both sides.

Comment: Thanks, @joanis, I will try to remember that